# Proper sentence structure and word usage when using the word, "imbue."

Tags: word-usage

I wrote, "Imbuing a love of reading in youth is a high calling," to a friend and then questioned my usage of the word, "imbue." Does anyone think the way I used it was incorrect in terms of structure? Would,"Imbuing youth with a love reading is a high calling," a better choice?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What did you find out in your own research ? 'Imbuing X with Y' seems to be the idiomatic expression, from just a brief Google.But the Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=imbuing+in%2Cimbuing+with&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimbuing%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimbuing%20with%3B%2Cc0 indicates an equal split between imbuing with/imbuing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fine. "Imbue" is a transitive verb and it works somewhat like "give". You can "imbue (the) youth with a love for reading" or you can "imbue a love of reading in (the) youth", just as you can "give me a book" or "give a book to me".

However, I would generally prefer "imbue (the) youth with a love for reading" and "give a book to me".

Comment: Not really; the person is the direct object, always. The other usage barely works with *instil*, but that's not really right either.

Comment: The *im-* and *in-* both mean *onto* or *into* (like *install*, *impregnate*)

Comment: I strongly disagree. Language is what we make it - and I perceive "imbue" to have a loose syntactic structure, as does "give". I wish that it were otherwise, but it simply is not. (The original poster likely agrees with me because they naturally used the form which you find improper).

The prefixes do not matter as far as I can tell.

Comment: I also strongly disagree. All the examples given by dictionaries for "imbue" are along the lines of "[X] is imbued with [Y]" where X is a person or their work, and Y is some quality or attribute.

Comment: I am confused; do you disagree with me or yourself? Anyway: Who cares what a dictionary says? I literally just said "language is what we make it". I am using descriptivistic linguistics, not prescriptivism. Even if we take your definition, that can be reinterpreted in the active voice as "[Y] imbues [X]", where Y is a non-agentive subject (namely a quality). Notice that this definition is a subpart of one of the options listed in the OP, where those definitions are agentive.

Comment: Please drop the manipulative rhetoric (you know very well what I mean). It is not "my" definition; and *changing* the normal use is not merely *describing* it, which I believe you also know very well.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't convinced me that your friend was concerned with word order. Your friend may simply be uncomfortable with using a less-common word. There may be a perception that the less common word is more pretentious.

***Instill***  [is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Instill%2Cimbue&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) than *imbue* in this situation. The two words are near synonyms, so you should be OK. However, there are subtle differences that may make you want to prefer *instill* after all:

***instill***:

> gradually but firmly establish (an idea or attitude, especially a desirable one) in a person's mind.

***imbue***:

> inspire or permeate with a feeling or quality.

*(both definitions from dictionary.com)*

*Instill* comes from a latin root meaning "drop". Another meaning of the word is to drip a precise amount of one liquid into another. So, *Instill*  has an implication of being measured.

On the other hand, *imbue* is also a synonym of "saturate". In Middle English, it meant precisely that. So if you say you want to "imbue" someone with a love of reading, it may imply you want to make someone love reading *above anything else*, which might be more than you might (or should) want.

Answer (score 0):

**To imbue ...** feels more natural here. However, as answered already, **instil** is a little better in meaning - imbue is more like "baptize". You'll be able to look up synonyms yourself, but a couple that I think could also work:

- To **encourage** ... [you can't really force it]
- To **inspire** [can't escape the spiritual connotations here :)]